# Python 3.6 and pip install errors on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install scikit using python3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and cannot seem to get pip to work properly.

I installed pip3 by running `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

That throws an error saying

```
pip3 install scikit
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 652, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 64
    async def _ag(): yield
                    ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function
```

If I try to just run pip I get this

```
  pip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to python and stackoverflow so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you download the file from pypi, download it to your server, and install it that way? Steps: 1) tar -xf file_name; 2) cd file_name; 3) python3 setup.py install

Comment: Maybe two versions of python 3 has been mixed up. What is the output if you call `pip3 --version` and `pip --version` ?

Comment: It certainly looks like this is an error with Python 3.6 and not the module you're installing. Pip may have become corrupted for some reason, or it was incomplete when downloaded.

Comment: @numbermaniac You were correct, something was wrong with my python install. I removed it and reinstalled it using conda this time and everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the one recommended on Pypi

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

And if that doesn't work just download the package from here

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.15.2

Comment: I've never used this module so I can't say for certain but it seems to be an error within the script. Try running python3 -m pip install if that doesn't work I would suggest uninstalling the module just in case you got a partial and are holding something broken. Then clear your cache and try again.